# How can i take array value in dropdown list.?

Tags: php, json

```
[
{
    "youname": "a",
    "youemail": "xyz@gmail.com",
    "studies": "elementary school",
    "civilstate": "single"
},
{
    "youname": "b",
    "youemail": "abcd@gmail.com",
    "studies": "secondary school",
    "civilstate": "single"
}
]
```

this is my .json file..! iam decoding it and json_decode and converting it to array format as below..

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [youname] => a [youemail] => xyz@gmail.com [studies] => elementary school [civilstate] => single )
 [1] => Array ( [youname] => b [youemail] => abcd@gmail.com[studies] => secondary school [civilstate] => single ))
```

can some one tell me how can i take  'Youemail' in dropdown list using PHP.

Comment: if it is valid array you should create loop to get it foreach($array as $item){ echo $item['youemail'];}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's in an array, use `$array =` and then the array.

You can then do:

```
<select>
foreach($array as $a)
{
    echo "<option value='".$a['youemail']."'";
}
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<?php 
$array = array ( 
    "0" => array(
        "youname" => "a", 
        "youemail" => "xyz@gmail.com", 
        "studies" => "elementary school", 
        "civilstate" => "single" 
    ),
    "1" => array( 
        "youname" => "b", 
        "youemail" => "abcd@gmail.com",
        "studies" => "secondary school", 
        "civilstate" => "single" 
    )
);

echo "<select>";
foreach($array as $each)
{
    echo "<option value='".$each['youemail']."'>".$each['youemail']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```